# WKWebView with embedded iframe player causes bad access when trying to disconnect from airplay

Tags: ios, iframe, avplayer, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView which loads request with this [url](https://mvs.wtf/xwRmSf_bjV1ItTgJoa-bTQ/QCVhDyKboyjEwKUFIdUUbw?autoplay=1&loop=1) which is after loaded plays inline video and can be  switched to full screen , when switched to full screen the native ios player appears, there is airplay button in that player letting user to stream video via airplay, there is no problem with connection to airplay and streaming play, pause etc.

The problem is that when i try to switch playback back to app from the airplay switch menu it causes bad access exception with log :

```
Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x283cbe310; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> 

    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x108054960; requestedReason: MediaPlayback; reason: MediaPlayback; flags: PreventTaskSuspend | PreventTaskThrottleDown | WantsForegroundResourcePriority>;
}

[ProcessSuspension]  0x1183e1018 - ProcessAssertion() PID 29725 Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 29725[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

---

The connection indicator also looks strange when connected to airplay

[image: The connection indicator also looks strange when connected to airplay]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem was in a third part lib which has categories on NSObject which where overriding copyWithZone method and were causing BAD_ACCESS, so removing the lib and implementing its functionality on project side solved the problem.